# Serial port data availability problem

Tags: .net, visual-c++

I am new to this type of programming..i just want some help...regarding what to do when u need to extract the data from the serial port..and how to check that tha data is available in the serial port..so that no data loss is there....

Answer (score 0):

You dont access the serial port directly. The O/S provides a device driver with a set of API function for use of the serial port.

You open the driver with the CreateFile function and get a handle to the driver. Using this handle you call the functions of the as found in the [Communications Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363195%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

When your serial port ist configured properly you can read the data using ReadFile. Using overlapped I/O you can get a handle to a wait event, that's signaled when data is available. As an opposite you can wait for an event as "data available" with the [WaitCommEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363479%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function.

Since the data is received with an ISR into an driver internal buffer, you can read the data without losing characters.